# How much does Google Maps SDK for Android Street view cost per API call?

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps-api-3

I am building a Flutter app that uses the Google Maps SDK for Android to show street view images.

Can somebody provide a simple Simon explanation of how much this service costs and what free quotas are on offer?

Also, whilst showing a Street View image if the user scrolls down the street does this count as a second API call?

Comment: You could read a bit more [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-and-pricing/pricing#static-street-view)

Answer (score 0):

Calling Google maps SDK for Android does not charge anything
Google Maps SDK includes basic static features like Roadmap view, satellite view, hybrid view.

but calling street view APIs will charge you.
for static street view will charge 0.007 USD per each API (7.00 USD per 1000) /month
for Dynamic street view will charge 0.014 USD per each API (14.00 USD per 1000) /month

Comment: Many thanks for the response. Out of interest, once in street view, when a user pivots the view or scrolls down a street, do such actions count as extra API calls?